# rpm database lost, how to proceed?

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, dnf

I completely lost the rpm directory under /var/lib with no way to recover it. (I know what I should have done...) I have made a new one (rpm --initdb) but of course rpm and yum no longer know what's on the system. Is there a way to repopulate the database so I can do things like yum check-update again and actually get results? Or is this a lost cause. If so, how to proceed?

I'm running Centos Stream release 8.

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

1. You download and install using `rpm` the `centos-release-XX-XX.noarch.rpm` package.
2. `find /usr /etc -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -P$(nproc) dnf --cacheonly whatprovides | sort -u > /tmp/packages.txt`
3. You manually download the resulting packages into e.g. `/tmp/packages`
4. `cd /tmp/packages && rpm -ivh --noscripts --notriggers --justdb *rpm`

You're all set.

Item N2 could be quite slow, there's a faster method but it's more complicated.